# Restricting elements (child) from overflowing it's container (parent) width

Tags: html, css, width

I'm trying to wrap two **div** elements inside an outer **main** element.

I want the inner elements (**box-one** and **box-two**) to take up the full **width** (i.e **100%)** of it's parent (the **item-wrap** container).

But, the problem is that when I set the value of the boxes width in percentage, **it will break out** of its parent container.

I'm not sure how to fix this except by setting the **width to auto**. (see box-one style).

```css
    body{
        background-color: lightblue; 
        font-size: 24px;
        }
    .item-wrap{
        border: 3px solid red;
        max-width: 180px;
        height: 250px;
        padding:8px;
        }
    #box-one{
        background-color: skyblue; 
        width: auto; /* not sure why 100% cause it to overflow x container */
        height: 140px;
        border: 2px solid orange;
        }
    #box-two{
        border: 3px solid green;
        width: 100%;
        height: 110px;
        background-color:tomato;
        padding: 10px 8px;
        }
```

```html
     <body>
        <main class="item-wrap">
            <div id="box-one">BOX ONE</div>
            
            <div id="box-two">BOX TWO</div>
        </main>
    </body>
```

Comment: the easiest solution is to not set width at all

Comment: I always use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`, with that, the elements overall width will be width + padding + border (not margin). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: I'll go for this *{box-sizing: border-box}. Thanks all